# Error trying to pre render React into html template with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to parse my react app into my index.html with webpack, however I keep getting the following error: `ERROR in Template execution failed: ReferenceError: window is not defined`

What I have so far

client/public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Anon's Website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"><%=
    require('../appPrerender.js')
  %></div> // EJS format
</body>
</html>
```

client/appPrerender.js

```
import App from './app';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
module.exports = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App/>);
```

webpack.common.js (excerpt)

```
plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: '!!ejs-loader!'+path.join(__dirname,'client/public/index.html')
  })]
```